FSD распределение по срезам
Пытаюсь разобраться в Feature-Sliced Design. Не смог найти конкретной информации либо примеров, но вопрос такой. Могу ли я срезы делить на новые срезы? Конкретный пример:
Лейаут я раположил в app/layouts. Хедер в widgets/header. В хедере у меня горизонтальное многоуровневое меню. Структура допустим примерно такая:
<Menu>
  <MenuItem/>
  <MenuItem/>
  <MenuItem>
    <Dropdown/>
  </MenuItem>
</Menu>

Вопрос в том где расположить компоненты меню? Можно ли создавать widgets/header/menu? Или правильно widgets/header/ui/menu.tsx и item.tsx(там же где и header.tsx)? Какой-то конкретики в документации я не нашел. В различных примерах тоже. Везде максимум один срез делают. Но куда тогда будет правильнее менюшку вставлять? Т.к. более нижние слои мне кажется не особо подходят для этого.
